# Can the precision of SQL Server 2008 TIME be reduced to only hours and minutes?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, time, precision

With SQL Server 2008 the `time` data type has an optional precision argument (default is 7). With this you can control how many fractional decimal places are stored and displayed.

```
DECLARE @time time(3)
SET @time = GETDATE()
PRINT @time
```

The above would print this,

```
10:47:25.347
```

The documentation says the smallest precision is `time(0)`. This would store and print `10:47:25`.

Is it possible to reduce the precision even more, to eliminate/zero out seconds: `10:47`?

I know this can be done manually by adding a constraint (`DATEPART(seconds, @time) = 0`), performing math on data entry to zero out the seconds, and manually format when printing, but I am looking for a simplier way to just define a field in a table as "hours and minutes", in much the same way that the `date` type allows you to define a field as "just the date, no time component".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. It is not possible to reduce the precision of the `time` datatype any further than `time(0)`

Answer (score 2):

Use smalldatetime and ignore the date bit (it will be 01 Jan 1900). It has minute accuracy.

As useful as time is, this is how we did in the olden days (SQL Server 2005 and before :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @time = convert(varchar(5),getdate(),8)
```

Here you are casting the result of GETDATE to a VARCHAR and formating it with the [modifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) 8 that means time format.

**EDIT:** This is giving you a string, maybe is not the result you are looking for.

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

If the interval you want is one of the SQL Server recognized intervals (Minute, Hour, Day, etc... then another option you might consider, is that you define your own datatype, (say you want hours) and then store it as an integer which is just an ***absolute*** hour number, starting from some base reference time (or use the same base reference time that SQL Server uses (midnight 1 Jan 1900)

Convert from the stored integer value, (`@IntVal`), to the actual hour as a datetime, (`@realDT`)using the following.  (assuming `@baseDatetime` is defined as the base time

```
Declare @baseDatetime smalldatetime 
Set @baseDatetime = 0 -- for 1 Jan 1900, or  
Set @baseDatetime = 'd Month yyyy'  for some other base

 @realDT->@IntVal:  @IntVal = DateDiff(hour, @baseDatetime, @realDT)  
 @IntVal->@realDT:  @realDT = DateAdd(hour, @IntVal, @baseDatetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having a problem with storage space, using CHAR(5) will only increase the issue, use DATALENGTH to check:

```
SELECT
 DATALENGTH(CONVERT(CHAR(5), GETDATE(), 8)) Char5 --> 5 bytes
,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(TIME(7), GETDATE()))    Time7 --> 5 bytes
,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(TIME(6), GETDATE()))    Time6 --> 5 bytes
,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(TIME(5), GETDATE()))    Time5 --> 5 bytes
,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(TIME(4), GETDATE()))    Time4 --> 4 bytes
,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(TIME(3), GETDATE()))    Time3 --> 4 bytes
,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(TIME(2), GETDATE()))    Time2 --> 3 bytes
,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(TIME(1), GETDATE()))    Time1 --> 3 bytes
,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(TIME(0), GETDATE()))    Time0 --> 3 bytes
```

Considering that CHAR(5) uses the same space of TIME(7), why won't you use TIME(7)?

A better option is to use TIME(2) or using a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15#TsqlProcedure) and a smallint column to store only minutes and time:

```
CREATE TABLE #StoreTime (
    TimeSmall SMALLINT
    , TimeReal AS CONVERT(TIME(0), DATEADD(MINUTE, TIMESMALL, '0:0:0')) )

DECLARE @TIME TIME = GETDATE()
INSERT #StoreTime VALUES (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, '0:0:0', @TIME))

SELECT *
    , DATALENGTH(TIMESMALL) --> 2 bytes
FROM #StoreTime
```

Although it uses less storage space it will cost to the CPU, if other processes are using the field as time they are going to be really slow because of the dateadd and conversion "implicit" of the computed column